# What're the relations between 127.0.0.0/8 and 127.0.0.1?

Tags: ip, ip-address

What're the relations between 127.0.0.0/8 and 127.0.0.1?

As per this [post](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56492/can-i-capture-127-0-0-0-and-0-0-0-0-network-using-wireshark?newreg=877f9d2362344e5488c197f1268e388f), it seems that they are the same thing. I am a newbie at the network, could somebody shed some light on this question?

ADDED:
Does it mean the data send to 127.0.0.1:502 could be received with the program which listens on 127.255.255.254:502?

Comment: @Zac67 Does it mean the data send to `127.0.0.1:502` could be received with the program which listens on `127.255.255.254:502`?

Comment: No - 127.0.01 and 127.255.255.254 share the same loopback interface but they're not a single IP address. But you could send a udp datagram from 127.0.0.1:502 to 127.255.255.254:502 without a problem.

Comment: @Zac67 What about TCP?

Comment: Absolutely the same - replace "send UDP datagram" with "connect TCP socket".

Comment: @Zac67 It seems that you are wrong after I did a test on Ubuntu.  "sudo nc -l 127.0.0.1 502" starts a TCP server. And "sudo nc 127.0.0.1 502" could successfully establish the connection whereas "sudo nc 127.255.255.254 502" couldn't.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Zac67 But you said :"But you could send a udp datagram from 127.0.0.1:502 to 127.255.255.254:502 without a problem." I am confused now.

Comment: "Send from IP:port" = send with IP:port as source; "send to IP:port" = with IP:port as destination. I was trying to point out that all those loopback addresses share a (virtual) network, so they can communicate with each other. They're different addresses still - which you verified in Ubuntu.